# Using an Intent to load a Youtube URL crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube

I am using a simple `Intent` to load a Youtube video and for some reason it crashes our app every time.

```
PUCObjects.PUCYoutubeItem item = groupedItems.get(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+item.videoId));
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Which gives me the following crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.puc.mobile/com.puc.mobile.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
at com.parse.ParsePlugins.set(ParsePlugins.java:35)
at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.initialize(ParsePlugins.java:149)
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:189)
at com.puc.mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

No idea why it talks about `Parse`. I am using that in our app, but it shouldn't have anything to do with loading a Youtube video.

Comment: Um, your stack trace is not coming from the code in your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare - That is the stack trace I get every time it crashes.

Comment: *it shouldn't have anything to do with loading a Youtube video* - it doesn't. Logcat is telling you exactly what the problem is ("ParsePlugins is already initialized") and where the problem is in your code (MainActivity.java, line 91)

Comment: "That is the stack trace I get every time it crashes" -- that's fine, but it is coming from something other than what you have in your question. As adelphus notes, your problem is in `onCreate()` method, where it is calling `initialize()` on a `Parse` object. The code in your question would not appear to be from an `onCreate()` method. It certainly is not calling `initialize()` on a `Parse` object.

Comment: Thanks guys. Got to the root of the `Parse` issue and everything is fixed.